# Wordpress: How can I make a bumped post show up in RSS again? Is there a value I can reset?

Tags: wordpress, post, rss, feed

Sometimes I want to update an older post and bump it to the top, but by default in Wordpress that doesn't create a new entry in RSS (I'm using FeedBurner on top of WP if that makes a difference).

How can I make it show up there again without reposting and deleting the old post?

Thanks, Wordpress gurus.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this by changing the date of the post to the current date.

You can do that from the Edit Post page while you're updating the post contents, just look for the 'Published on' date and click on the 'edit' link next it, and then be sure to save the edit.  The real feed will be updated instantly but it may take some time for Feedburner to update.

If you've already updated the post and just want to move it to the top, you don't even need to go to the Edit Post page - just go to the main Posts page showing your list of posts, and hold your cursor over the post title so that the Quick Edit link appears.  Click the Quick Edit option and you'll be able to change the date.

Comment: That's how I already bump my posts, but it doesn't result in a new entry in the feed as far as Google Reader is concerned. It gets bumped to the top of the feed, but GR knows it's seen it before.

Comment: OK well that method does definitely bump posts to the top of the feed, just like you asked for. Google Reader must be seeing that either the post URL or post ID is the same as it has seen previously so it's not considering it to be a new entry. Have you tried changing the URL, for example appending something like 'updated' or 'july-2012' etc. Although this may not work if GR is also taking into consideration the post ID which is also show for each post in the feed.